# Visual Studio publish only changed files by content instead of by file 'modified date'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis-8, webdeploy, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 'Publish' option for ASP.NET applications allows to publish files using 'web deploy' with option to publish only changed files.

The problem is that it is comparing file's "modified date" to determine if file has been modified after server's file modified date instead of actually comparing the content of the file.

This is a problem because if you remove the default publish folder from your local computer (where all previous published files are saved) then you will loose track of latest publish state thus you will be required to publish everything again.

Is there an option to publish changed files by content and not by modified date?

Comment: Why is it a problem to publish everything again?

Comment: You could manually publish a modified file by right click on that file or folder and select Publish.[image](https://i.imgur.com/trqZXzE.png)

Comment: @ADyson It is a large project publishing everything takes time (5 min).

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I don't know which files were modified. Project has thousand of files and many are changed between released. I need the publish system to determine which file needs to be published.

Comment: Surely your source control system will tell you what's been modified between releases? Also what's the reason for deleting your publish folder? How often does that really happen? If it's a rare case, then surely the occasional 5 minutes to publish it not a big issue, if most publishing takes much less time. I'm just trying to tease out whether it's worth the time to look into and then apply some kind of solution for this, vs the time which will actually be saved in reality. It _sounds_ like an irritant rather than an everyday issue - but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ADyson I have about 100 different VS solutions on my source control (TFS). If you multiply those 5 min for each it is alot of time.

Also, it is a problem to publish from more than one machine since each machine has it's own modified-date depending on when the first publish was done on it.

Comment: in my opinion, web deploys only published or update that folder or file which you modified other files and folder remains the same.

Comment: -on the publish -> setting -> File publish option -> un check the "Delete all existing files prior to publish"  
it will save some of your time

Comment: This is so frustrant and so 2001, in any moment VS ask to install Frontpage 98 and publish in geocities. Cmon.... I think I could update it through IRC DCC